# Android volley library UTF convert in ISO

Tags: android, utf-8, iso, utf-16, android-volley

I am using the Android volley library and the StringRequest Class.

The application is in French and there are some special characters using 2 octets like:
é, è, ê, à, ù, etc...

The String returned has replaced those characters by something like: Ã©

How could I get the special characters using Android Volley ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is basically to convert the String UTF-8 to ISO like said in this post:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.java.help/64N6vLAqVZU